# Preventing an edit control from rendering

Tags: winapi

I've got an edit control where I'd like to disable any rendering, but leave it as interactive (similar to an owner-drawn control). Right now, I have subclassed the Window and captured WM_PAINT, such as

```
SetWindowSubclass(box, [](HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam, UINT_PTR, DWORD_PTR) -> LRESULT {
    if (msg != WM_PAINT)
        return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
    PAINTSTRUCT paint;
    BeginPaint(hwnd, &paint);
    EndPaint(hwnd, &paint);
    return 0;
}, 0, 0);
```

This has worked fine to disable almost all of the edit box's rendering. However, when interacting with it, it still occasionally clears the area where it would render, causing airspace issues when I am rendering in that space with Direct3D.

How can I complete the subclass such that the edit box never renders anything?

Comment: You can't get this reliable.  The EDIT control dates from the 1980s, an era where Windows had to run on a 640 KB 386SUX machine.  It committed a few sins to make that responsive enough, it paints directly to the window instead of always using Invalidate() and leave the painting up to the WM_PAINT message handler.  Add 25 years of appcompat to prevent that from getting fixed.

Comment: Man. But a Unicode-aware edit control would be so much hassle for me to write myself. :(

Comment: What sort of interactivity do you need? If you don't need mouse, you could wrap the EDIT in a small parent HWND that clips it to prevent it drawing; or possibly use `SetWindowRgn()`. In both cases, the control can still take focus and handle keyboard input, but won't be clickable, though you could perhaps try forwarding mouse input to it.

Comment: Well, what I could really use is "All of the normal functionality of the edit box". Forwarding mouse input, that I could do.